# Threads execute not at the same time

Tags: java, multithreading

I have three threads, each thread have to do some manipulation with the instance(q) of same class (Q), periodically (That's why I use Thread.sleep() in the method somecheck). Main task is to make thread execute not at the same time, so at one time can execute only one thread.
I tried to put content of run method each thread into synchronized (q){}, but I do not understand where to put notify and wait methods.

```
class Q {
        boolean somecheck(int threadSleepTime){
        //somecheck__section, if I want to stop thread - return false;

            try{
            Thread.sleep(threadSleepTime);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {                
            }
            return true;
        }
}



class threadFirst extends Thread  {
    private Q q;
    threadFirst(Q q){this.q=q;}

    public void run(){
        do{
            //Working with object of class Q
        }
        while(q.somecheck(10));
    }
}

class threadSecond extends Thread  {
    private Q q;
    threadSecond(Q q){this.q=q;}

    public void run(){
        do{
            //Working with object of class Q
        }
        while(q.somecheck(15));
    }
}

class threadThird extends Thread  {

    private Q q;
    threadThird(Q q){this.q=q;}

    public void run(){
        do{
            //Working with object of class Q
        }
        while(q.somecheck(20));
    }
}

class run{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Q q = new Q();
        threadFirst t1 = new threadFirst(q);
        threadSecond t2 = new threadSecond(q);
        threadThird t3 = new threadThird(q);
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: yes! all works ok, but threads is not synchronized and threads execute at the same time.

Comment: Your code is full of errors, it's hard for us to get a handle on it.

Comment: this code doesn't even compile, either fix it as asked already or it will be deleted

Comment: You are right! I have fixed it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to put any `notify()` and `wait()` methods if you use `synchronized` blocks inside all of the methods, for example:

```
class threadFirst extends Thread {
    ...
    public void run() {
        synchronized (q) {
            //your loop here
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Your idea mean thats - first thread will execute and stop, then second will execute and stop, than third will execute and stop. But, the hole idea is to do something in first thread, than another thread will do something, than first thread can do something again.

Comment: After thread execute "Working with object of class Q" section and execute q.somecheck(), thread need to give opportunity to execute for other threads.

Comment: @user2963950 seems like I've got it, then you may move `synchronized` block into the loop's body